# "Дай мне" vs "дайте мне"

Tags: выбор-слова, повелительное-наклонение

What is the difference between **дай мне** and **дайте мне**?

Comment: this is really a simple question, i'm sure a chapter on Russian imperatives in a textbook should provide the answer, provided you know where to look of course

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first imperative can be used when addressing a single person whom you usually call **ты** (a child or somebody close enough to you). The second version is applicable to somebody you call **вы** (in most such cases you also add **пожалуйста** for politeness, '*please*') or to multiple listeners.